# Show that this is a metric?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $0 < a < 1$. Define $d^a$ by $(d(x,y))^a$. Show that $d^a$ is a metric on $X$.

I was able to show everything except the triangle inequality. It's obvious that we can write

$$(d(x,z))^a\le(d(x,y)+d(y,z))^a$$

but I'm not sure where to go from there. Any hints? Sorry about the annoying format; I'm new to this site.

Comment: $(s+t)^{a} \leq s^{a}+t^{a}$ for all $s,t \geq 0$.

Comment: Welcome to the website. Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations in future (I have done it for you this time).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $0<\alpha < 1$ and $d(x,y)$ is metric, show that $((d(x,y))^{\alpha}$ is metric.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3178991/if-0-alpha-1-and-dx-y-is-metric-show-that-dx-y-alpha-is-metr)

Comment: Yep. Thanks to all three of you!